# Converting C# to Java. Calling newInstance() of generic class' constructor always returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, c#, selenium

I'm fairly new to Java. I am trying to port code from C# and I am having issues with creating an instance of a generic class but I keep getting NullPointerExceptions. Been on this for a while and need another set of more experienced eyes.

Here is the C# version:

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>(WebdriverContext context) where T : WebSiteControl
    {
        //If type has constructor with 1 parameter and is type IContext. Then use that.
        //Else use default constructor.

        var type = typeof(T);

        //First constructor attempt.
        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { context.GetType() });
        if (ctor != null)
        {
            var ctrl = (T)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { context });
            return ctrl;
        }

        //Second constructor attempt.
        ctor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (ctor != null)
        {
            var ctrl = (T)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { });
            ctrl.WebContext = context;
            return ctrl;
        }

        throw new Exception("No appropriate constructors found for " + type.Name);
    }
```

This works as intended.
Java version is as follows:

```
public static <T extends WebSiteControl> T CreateInstance (Class<T> clazzType, WebdriverContext context) throws Exception{
    //If type has constructor with 1 parameter and is type IContext. Then use that.
    //Else use default constructor.
    Constructor ctor = clazzType.getSuperclass().getConstructor(new Class[] {context.getClass()});

    //First constructor attempt.
    if (ctor != null)
    {            
        T ctrl = (T)ctor.newInstance(new Object[] {context});
        return ctrl;
    }

    //Second constructor attempt.
    ctor = clazzType.getSuperclass().getConstructor(ctor.getClass());
    if (ctor != null)
    {
        T ctrl = (T) ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { });
        ctrl.WebContext = context;
        return ctrl;
    }      
    throw new Exception("No appropriate constructors found for " + clazzType.toString()+".");
}
```

This works all as it should until I get to the line

```
T ctrl = (T)ctor.newInstance(new Object[] {context});
```

Any time I try to use newInstance() in any form it throws the NullPointerException.
[ErrorMessage.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Bvw.png)

I feel like I am missing something super obvious.
Anyone know what I've missed?

Comment: I don't know any of these things, but it seems like there is something wrong with the instance of WebdriverContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `NullPointerException` is wrapped in an `InvocationTargetException`, the actual source has to lie somewhere in the constructor that is called, according to [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-):

> Throws: InvocationTargetException - if the underlying constructor throws an exception.

The code you posted seems fine.

Unrelated detail: `getConstructor()` doesn't return null if no Method was found but throws an exception, so your second attempt will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! [@MDK](http://user:11948496) gave me the idea to look through the initialization of my other classes. Turns out in WebsiteControl I was setting up a variable on initialization which depended on another one which was only ever set in the constructor.

```
private WebdriverContext Webcontext;
private Webdriver driver = Webcontext.getDriver();
public WebSiteControl(WebdriverContext context){
    WebContext = context;
    webdriver = WebContext.getDriver();
}
```

I was mixing my logic with C# where you can make a variable with a {get, private set}.

Fixed by adding webdriver = WebContext.getDriver(); to every constructor (not ideal, but hey) and not initializing the driver first:

```
private WebdriverContext Webcontext;
private Webdriver driver;
public WebSiteControl(WebdriverContext context){
    WebContext = context;
    webdriver = WebContext.getDriver();
}
```